# React Typescript setting state based of previous state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Im learning typescript and cant find out what does this mean. The error says `Type 'FriendListItem[] | null' is not an array type.ts(2461).`  But when typing FriendList[], that means it will be array of FriendListItem items, right ?

```
  interface FriendListItem {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  address: string;
}

const App = () => {
  const { data, done } = useFetchAll(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
  );
  const [friendList, setFriendList] = useState<FriendListItem[] | null>(null);

  const addToFriendList = (friend: FriendListItem): void => {
    **setFriendList((prevstate) => [...prevstate, { friend }]);**
  };

  const removeFromFriendList = (id: string) => {};

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Layout>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact />
          <Route path="/everyone" exact>
            <Everyone data={data} done={done} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/everyone/:userId">
            <UserDetail addToFriendList={addToFriendList} />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Layout>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Edit: Adding my testconfig file, which is generated from cra --template typescript, did not change anything

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: you should include your tsconfig.json file and what version of TS you are using

Comment: You are trying to apply a spread to null, e.g. `[...null, { friend }]`. Pass an empty array as the default value to `useState`

Comment: @JaredSmith just did and it still throw that error

Comment: @Daniels0n you have to change the generic type parameter too: `useState<FriendListItem[]>([]);` *again*, you can't use a spread on something that you've told the compiler might be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `friendList` is an `array` or `null`. So need to check before use spread operator:

```
  const addToFriendList = (friend: FriendListItem): void => {
    setFriendList((prevstate) => prevstate ? [...prevstate, friend] : [friend]);
  };
```